# Kurento media server DTMF and VAD detection

Tags: kurento

We are building PoC with Kurento media server and I was looking how to implement DTMF and Voice activity detection in Kurento. 
Dtmf detection is possible on gstreamer with rtpdtmfdepay and dtmfdetect elements and for VAD I was looking at [VAD plugin???](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-speexenc.html)

So for example DTMF detection, what has to be done on Kurento side to implement such a functionality - do you develop [kurento models](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html) based on GStreamer, is that enough?

Has anyone tried something like that that could share some insight/example/code?

Regards!